# Finite difference method for the electric field of the electron gun

Tags: finite-element, matlab, finite-difference, python

Can anybody help me to find books or MATLAB code examples for solving electric field of the electron gun(fig.1)with finite difference method? Python code examples are also perfect.
[image: the schematic of the electron gun]

The electron gun includes three electrodes,1,2,3.The voltages of three electrodes are 0V,100V,1000V,respectively.

Comment: Do you need to find the electric field and the trajectory of electrons?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Your question in essence asks others to write a code for you.

Comment: I have tried to solve this problem with MATLAB,  but I think the MATLAB codes  is not perfect. So I want to find some similar examples.

Answer (score 2):

I think the canonical way to solve this problem (at least in a classroom setting) is to approximate the Laplacian (the PDE that governs the scalar potential $V$) using finite differences in Cartesian coordinates. When you apply Gauss-Jacobi algorithm to such a linear system, you end up with a particularly simple scheme: at each successive iteration, every potential sample $V_{i,j}$ should be overwritten with the average of its four neighbors (up/down/left/right). Your dirichlet conditions ($V = 1000$, etc) just become "dead" sample points whose values never change, but they do still contribute to the averages of any adjacent "live" points.

So initially, you'll have an all-zero grid of $V_{i,j}$'s, except for the dirichlet samples that are initialized with the prescribed values. Each iteration, updated values of $V$ will "creep" across the model one point at a time. In the limit (infinite number of iterations) the $V_{i,j}$'s will converge to the solution to the Laplacian (albeit rather slowly). You can embellish the scheme slightly into Gauss-Seidel or successive over-relaxation if you wish.

Once you are satisfied with your solution for $V_{i,j}$, you can use it to find the $\vec E$ field, using the usual relationship $\vec E=-\nabla V$. This postprocessing step can also be accomplished by finite differences.

This isn't necessarily a great method. But it's easy to derive and requires minimal programming skill, so it's commonly taught. See, for example, http://faculty.otterbein.edu/DRobertson/compsci/em-stud.pdf, you could probably find other similar materials with some searching.